# How do I get the value after decimal?

Tags: c#

Example -> 4.11 
I need to get 11 which is the value after decimal

How do i get that in C#?

Comment: What data-type is the input?  And what is the general rule?  For instance, what if the input is 4.011?

Comment: Why do you want that?  There may be a better approach if the requirement is understood.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the value from the math.int of the value

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get the digits after the decimal point (if exists) as a raw string, just use string manipulation:

```
double myNumber = 4.0001115;
string myString = myNumber.ToString();
string decimalSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
int index = myString.IndexOf(decimalSeparator);
string afterDecimal = (index >= 0 && !myString.EndsWith(decimalSeparator)) ? myString.Substring(index + decimalSeparator.Length) : "";
```

Otherwise if you mean get it as number by its own right, the other answers here are correct.

Comment: This would not work for me because my [`CurrentCulture`'s `NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9758585/284240) is `','` and `myNumber.ToString()` would be `4,0001115`.

Comment: @Tim good point, edited my post to support different formats. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's old but why dont put the value in an int so it shorts to a number without decimal.

And than subtract the value with the int number like this -->

```
double myValue = 4.11;
int myInteger = myValue // It's 4
double valueAfterDecimal = myValue - myInteger; // It's 4.11 - 4 = 0.11
int valueAsInt = Convert.ToInt16(valueAfterDecimal * 100) ;
// 0.11 *100 = 11.0 --> Convert to Int = 11
```

Comment: But the result should be 11.

Comment: I didn't noticed that. But you can simply take 0.11 * 100 and write it in an int-value to cut all other values after decimal.

Comment: Yes, but you miss the subtle detail, that the result should be 11, not 0.11.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple method which does preserve leading zeroes of the mantissa:

```
double number = -1234.056789;
string mantissa = string.Empty;
decimal fraction = (decimal)number % 1;
if (fraction != 0)
{
    mantissa = Math.Abs(fraction).ToString().Substring(2);
}
Console.WriteLine(mantissa);
Console.ReadKey();

Result: 056789
```